# Merge SourceList<T> and SourceCache<T, TKey>

Tags: c#, dynamic-data, rx.net

How can I merge SourceList and SourceCache<T, TKey>?

Demo Model

```
internal interface IModel { }
internal class ModelA : IModel
{ }

internal class ModelB : IModel
{ }
```

Demo instances

```
var sourceList = new SourceList<IModel>();
var sourceCache = new SourceCache<IModel, int>(m => m.GetHashCode());
```

Not compiling attempt to merge

```
sourceList.Connect().Merge(sourceCache.Connect()); // does not compile
```

Comment: I'm new to Rx. This compiles: `sourceList.Connect().Merge(sourceCache.Connect().ToListObservable());` but quite frankly no idea if this corresponds to what you're trying to do. You may also need this: `using System.Reactive.Linq;`. If this is not what you're looking for please let me know and I'll delete this comment.

Comment: `ToListObservable()` does not return an instance that implements `IObservable<IChangeSet<IModel>>`. This means, I cannot continue with any extension methods
of `DynamicData` (e.g. `Filter` or `Bind`).

Comment: How about this: `var merged = sourceList.Connect().Merge(sourceCache.Connect().RemoveKey());` ? This apparently *Removes the key from each change. This changes the change set from a cache change set to a list changeset*

Comment: `RemoveKey` seems to be the solution (y)